# How can I apply the appropriate color space and gamma transfer function to my ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an sRGB image sequence that I want to convert to .mp4. With this conversion, I want to preserve all sRGB and Gamma values from the original image sequence. For instance, I'd like my Red (255,0,0) values in my png files to be preserved in my video. This means that I want to convert using an RGB color space, and gamma encoded as sRGB for the transfer function.

Currently I'm using this ffmpeg command, which gives me accurate gamma but inaccurate RGB values. Any help would be great!

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -i input_%05d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -colorspace rgb -color_trc iec61966-2-1 -y output.mp4
```

Here is a frame with proper sRGB colors
[image]

Here is a frame after using the ffmpeg command. If you use a color picker, you can see that the RGB values are off.
[image]

Comment: Try just using `ffmpeg -r 60 -i input_%05d.png -c:v libx264rgb -y output.mp4`. `libx264rgb` is a codec intended to be use for RGB pixels. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: When I use the code you provided, the RGB values are correct but the entire black gamma strip in the image above has 0,0,0 color values

Comment: Hmmm. What's your ffmpeg version, system and the software with where you're probing the color? It works fine for me personally with latest `ffmpeg-full` on Windows 10 in VLC and the black colors range from `#010101` to `#060606`. Are other colors correct for you?

Comment: When I take a screen capture from VLC and examine the colors in photoshop, they all appear to be correct. However, when I extract a frame from the new video and analyze it in photoshop or after effects, that frame has 0,0,0 for pretty much all "black" values. I have a feeling that vlc is doing some sort of conversion to make the colors accurate on an sRGB monitor. OR there is embedded color information in the video

Comment: I still can't reproduce using your exact steps. Image taken with `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i output.mp4 -frames:v 1 output.png`, opened in Photoshop, all colors are preserved.  https://i.imgur.com/8f5mQ5i.png How do you extract the frame?

Comment: When I follow your steps and convert my image sequence into a new video back to a png sequence, then the numbers are correct. However, if I take the resulting mp4 file, open that in photoshop or after effects, and examine the black values, they are all off. 

So basically, use the original frame I provided, encode it using the command you provided (libx264rgb) and then open the resulting mp4 video in photoshop. Examine the colors. The blacks are off.

Comment: Here's  a video of my process
https://youtu.be/t2oqgFKTl0A

Answer (score 0):

I am going to "recycle" may [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75059375/4926757):

I recommend you to convert the video to BT.709, and mark the video as BT.709:

- Convert the video to BT.709 using scale filter:
  `scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv`
- Mark the video as BT.709 "TV range" (Limited range) using `bsf` filter:
  `-bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0:colour_primaries=1:transfer_characteristics=1:matrix_coefficients=1`

---

Command:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -i input_%05d.png -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0:colour_primaries=1:transfer_characteristics=1:matrix_coefficients=1 -y output.mp4
```

---

Note:
In case the PNG image file has an embedded ICC profile, the above solution may not work.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work well, however, I am getting rounding errors on my colors. I'd like to try using libx264rgb. When I try using it, the pixel format automatically changes from yuv420p to bgr24. This makes my image magenta and cyan and changes all of my colors. Do you have any suggestions on what pixel format to use with libx264 rgb to get colors without rounding errors?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It supposed to be `rgb24` or not set at all.  Remove `-pix_fmt yuv420p -colorspace rgb -color_trc iec61966-2-1`. In case the PNG files are non-standard, try: `ffmpeg -r 60 -i input_%05d.png -vf format=rgb24 -c:v libx264rgb -y output.mp4`

Comment: Ah, I see. With libx264rgb, are the gamma values not converted? Every time I use it, the RGB values are perfect but gamma is not correct.

Comment: If the input is sRGB and the output is sRGB there is no need for gamma correction. It's probably possible to apply manual gamma correction using `scale` filter (or `eq` filter or other filter). Execute `ffmpeg -h filter=scale` for all options of scale filter (use the `scale` filter before the `format` filter).